# Compare two columns in csv and write only unique values to another csv

Tags: java, csv

I am fairly new to java, I have a csv file with 8 columns and I need create new csv from that file with 5 columns. Now I have already done that, to read the csv and create a new one. But there are repeated data in original csv, and the scenario is, if the data are repeated, I only need to take a single row from that. For example:

> a, 123, value1, a@email.com
>
> a, 123, value1, a@email.com
>
> a, 123, value1, a@email.com
>
> a, 123, Value7, a@email.com
>
> b, 567, Value5, b@email.com
>
> b, 567, Value6, b@email.com
>
> b, 567, Value6, b@email.com

Like above values, a has value1 repeating 3 times, and b has Value6 repeating two times. In my new csv, I only need to write those value once. So that the ourput looks something like this:

> a, 123, value1, a@email.com
>
> a, 123, Value7, a@email.com
>
> b, 567, Value5, b@email.com
>
> b, 567, Value6, b@email.com

Below is the code I have written to read and write the csv file. I am finding it hard to get a logic for the above scenario. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        String row = "";
        List<List<String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Map newMap = new HashMap();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.csv"));
        row=br.readLine();
        while((row=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] line = row.split(",", -1);
            //System.out.println(line[4]);
            //newMap.put(line[1], line[4]);
            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String cell : line) {
              newList.add(cell);
             // System.out.println(newList.get(3));
            }
            data.add(newList);

        }

         FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("newFile.csv");
        //Write To New File
        //Add Headers
        csvWriter.append("User Name,"+"User LoginID,"+"User Position,"+"Permission,"+"Email Address"+"\n");
        for(List rowData:data) {
            if(rowData.toString().length()>1) {
            rowData.remove(5);
            rowData.remove(2);
            rowData.remove(4);
            newMap.put(rowData.get(0), rowData.get(3));
                csvWriter.append(String.join(",",rowData));
                csvWriter.append("\n");
        }
        }
        }

        csvWriter.flush();
        csvWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your question would get many more answers if you included some code.  Most people don't want to write a whole program to read and write csv files, but they would be happy to show you how to adjust your program to meet your needs.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong, Thanks for the info. I am new to this and this is my first question, so a bit naive I guess. I have updated the description with the code I am currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see how you're getting the values for user/permissions so I'm taking some liberty here by specifying some bits arbitrarily which I'm assuming you already have:

```java
Map<String,Set<String>> userToPermissionMap = new HashMap<>();
// read in CSV line by line
String[] lines = csvFileInput; // not actual code
for (String line : lines) {
    String rowData = line.split(",");
    String user = rowData[0];
    String permission = rowData[3];

    if (!userToPermissionMap.contains(user)) {
        userToPermissionMap.put(user, new HashSet<>());
    }
    userToPermissionMap.get(user).add(permission);
}
```

This only shows how to group the permissions per user. You'll still want to record the other details I'm guessing, but that should be straight forward to add as you see fit. Then you write it to a new CSV.

Alternatively you could delete rows that you find are duplicates. This could introduce the interesting problem of removing rows, then you moving to the next row, when in fact the row you just deleted got replaced with the next row.... do it in reverse if you follow this method. The approach will be similar to above though - you'll need to maintain a list of users and permissions already seen and only keep the rows where the user/permission combination has not yet been encountered.

Comment: Thanks Rob, it was my first time posting a question, so a bit naive. I just added the code and updated the description.

Comment: np - if it works for you pls feel free to give it an upvote. I'm trying to build up my score :)

Answer (score 0):

See what you think of this:

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

class Scratch {

    public static final int USER_COL = 0;
    public static final int LOGIN_ID_COL = 1;
    public static final int USER_POSITION_COL = 2;
    public static final int PERMISSION_COL = 3;
    public static final int EMAIL_COL = 4;
    private static Map<String, List<String>> userData = new HashMap<>();
    private static Map<String, Set<String>> userToPermissionMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.csv"));
        String header = br.readLine(); // store header for later use

        String rowEntry = null;
        while ((rowEntry = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = rowEntry.split(",");
            String user = row[USER_COL];
            String permission = row[PERMISSION_COL];

            // doesn't matter if we overwrite an entry here as we'll extract the unique permissions each time and ignore this afterwards
            userData.put(user, Arrays.asList(row));

            if (!userToPermissionMap.containsKey(user)) {
                userToPermissionMap.put(user, new HashSet<>()); // new user
            }
            userToPermissionMap.get(user).add(permission); // add permission to the Set
        }

        FileWriter csvWriter = new FileWriter("newFile.csv");
        csvWriter.append(header + "\n"); // copy of original header (may not need \n)

        for (String user : userToPermissionMap.keySet()) { // for each user
            for (String permission: userToPermissionMap.get(user)) { // for each unique permission
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                builder.append(user + ",");
                builder.append(userData.get(user).get(LOGIN_ID_COL) + ",");
                builder.append(userData.get(user).get(USER_POSITION_COL) + ",");
                builder.append(permission + ",");
                builder.append(userData.get(user).get(EMAIL_COL) + "\n");

                csvWriter.append(builder.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```